# Clustering of Superpixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a homework about clustering of superpixels and I have some difficulties with it. I am allowed to use VLFeat library to find superpixels only.

[image: The image I am processing:]

After finding superpixels, I am defining a Feature Vector for every superpixel with the values; [ (Average "R" value of all pixels in the superpixel) (Average "G" value of all pixels in the superpixel) (Average "B" value of all pixels in the superpixel) (Average "Hue" value of all pixels in the superpixel) (Average "Saturation" value of all pixels in the superpixel) (Average "Value" value of all pixels in the superpixel)].

After that I am sending feature vector and cluster number into built-in kmeans function to clustering superpixels.

```
function [] = segmentIt (impath, clusNum)

%run vlfeat tools%    
run ('vlfeat/toolbox/vl_setup');

%read input image%
image = imread (impath);
imDouble = im2double (image);

%save image W and H%
IH = size (image, 1);
IW = size (image, 2);

%convert input image to single%
imSingle = im2single (image);

%get superpixel data%
superPixels = vl_slic (imSingle, 80, 1);

%how many superpixel do we have?%
SPNUM = size (unique (superPixels), 1);

%changing color space for feature vector%
imHSV = rgb2hsv (image);

%create feature vector with [averageR averageG averageB averageH averageS averageV]%
FEATURE = zeros (SPNUM, 6);

for i=0:SPNUM-1
    K = find (superPixels == i);
    L = zeros (size(K,1), 2);
    L(:,1) = ceil (K(:,1) ./ IW);
    L(:,2) = mod(K(:,1), IW) + 1;
    intensityTotalR = 0;
    intensityTotalG = 0;
    intensityTotalB = 0;
    vTotal = 0;
    sTotal = 0;
    hTotal = 0;

    for j = 1 : size (L, 1)
        intensityTotalR = intensityTotalR + ( imDouble (L(j,1), L(j,2), 1));
        intensityTotalG = intensityTotalG + ( imDouble (L(j,1), L(j,2), 2));
        intensityTotalB = intensityTotalB + ( imDouble (L(j,1), L(j,2), 3));
        vTotal = vTotal + imHSV (L(j,1), L(j,2), 3);
        sTotal = sTotal + imHSV (L(j,1), L(j,2), 2);
        hTotal = hTotal + imHSV (L(j,1), L(j,2), 1);
    end

    FEATURE(i+1,:) = [intensityTotalR/size(L,1) intensityTotalG/size(L,1) intensityTotalB/size(L,1) vTotal/size(L,1) sTotal/size(L,1) hTotal/size(L,1)]; 
end

RESULT = kmeans (FEATURE, clusNum);
newIMAGE = zeros(IH, IW, 3);
colorMultiplier = 1/(clusNum+5);

for i=1:clusNum
    K = find (RESULT == i);
    for j = 1: size (K,1)

        L = find (superPixels == K(j,1));
        S = zeros (size(L,1), 2);
        S(:,1) = ceil (L(:,1) ./ IW);
        S(:,2) = ceil (mod (L(:,1), IW)) + 1;

        for z = 1:size(S,1)
            newIMAGE (S(z,1), S(z,2), 1) = colorMultiplier * i;
            newIMAGE (S(z,1), S(z,2), 2) = colorMultiplier * i;
            newIMAGE (S(z,1), S(z,2), 3) = 1;
        end

    end
end

imshow (newIMAGE)

end
```

After running my function, the resultant image does not seem very good. Any idea what is missing in my code?

Result image:

[image: Result Image]

**EDIT**

Ok, that's really weird. I recolour my superpixels and this is what I got.

[image: Result of recolouring of superpixels]

**EDIT-2**

I edited my code in the light of what `lennon310` said. And wolaa. The problem was the way of my usage of find() function.

That's the result when cluster number is equal to 5.

[image]

From now on, I will try to upgrade my feature vector to get better results.
Thanks `lennon310`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks good to me. `colorMultiplier * i` as a value less than 1, `imshow` should be fine but double check with `imagesc` to observe the difference, though there may be no visual difference.

Without taking a look at your image, it is not easy to point out the reason. How would you define 'good' for a clustering result? Clustering method is very sensitive to feature density, size, and the metric you use. I always like to use [this image](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html) to show how different clustering algorithms lead to drastic segmentation results (unfortunately there is no k-means in the example though). Probably you may just need to try other methods if the segmentation from k-means is far away from your expectation.

### [image]

**EDIT**

If you are using k-means, perhaps you can reduce the feature before a full implementation. For example you can just use the RGB space feature, and reduce the iteration by setting the `'Replicates'` a smaller number in [kmeans](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html), observe the segmentation results before you move on to further steps.

Given the superpixels, can you recover the original image? If yes you can try to see the image of `RESULT` by `reshape` method. This can test whether `kmeans` work well before you finally set values in `newIMAGE`

**EDIT2**

Change

```
K = find (superPixels == i);
L = zeros (size(K,1), 2);
L(:,1) = ceil (K(:,1) ./ IW);
L(:,2) = mod(K(:,1), IW) + 1;
```

to

```
[K1,K2] = find (superPixels == i);
L = zeros (length(K1), 2);
L(:,1) = K1;
L(:,2) = K2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is my image and my result;

Image: https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/BSDS300/html/dataset/images/color/42049.html
Result: http://i.imgur.com/9mwHjmf.jpg

Comment: Thank you erhan. It's a nice resource. Are your result from that bird segmentation? Why there are so many periodic patterns?

Comment: I am very new on this website, and I have edited my comment for 3 times :)

I had written exactly the same thing, I am getting some patterns. Yes this is the result of the bird image. I think I am playing with wrong values in some of the loops. Do you agree?

Comment: I added the image on your post, and updated my answer for the suggestion. Maybe the iteration number is too large, or maybe kmeans is not a good option. You can try to reduce the feature first, as my answer says. Thanks

Comment: I thank you very much lennon310. I will try what you said. I cannot vote your answer up as my reputation is too low to do it. Sorry for that.

Comment: You are very welcome to update your result. And we can try to find out the possible solution then

Comment: given the superpixels, can you recover the original image? If yes you can try to see the image of RESULT by some reshape method. This can test whether kmeans work well before you finally set values in newIMAGE

Comment: I recoloured my superpixels, and added the result on my answer.

Comment: is that after kmeans, or just after you get the superpixels? Are you required to use superpixels for this segmentation?

Comment: After getting superpixels. Yes I am required to use superpixels, that's the point of my homework (: Is my usage of find() function true? I am in doubt about it.

Comment: what do you get for size(superpixel)? is it the same size of your original image but just labelled with different numbers?

Comment: have a try on my update. You also need to change the corresponding code after kmeans, but let's see whether superpixel part works for you first

Comment: i got to go, just let me know the progress. will check it later.  K = find (RESULT == i); looks good since RESULT is a 1d vector. but if you are positioning the superpixel (2d matrix), you may use two variables to get the values as I did in the update. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

hope this post is not too late to draw your interest. I have some problem to solve using SLIC + grouping. But I found some modification may lead to better results:

1. If you clustering using only RGB or only HSV, results will be better than using the combination of them, the reason might be they are different in scales.
2. You may use mean shift rather than k-means if you are not sure how many segments to get.
3. For RGB, use median instead of mean you may have better results.
4. The code below may improve the speed quiet a bit:

   function [ newSegs ] = supp_vl( input_im )

   ```
   %SUPP compute the superpixel using vl feat function

   imDouble = im2double (input_im);

   %save image W and H%
   IH = size (imDouble, 1);
   IW = size (imDouble, 2);

   %convert input image to single%
   imSingle = im2single (imDouble);

   %get superpixel data%
   segments = vl_slic (imSingle, 80, 1);

   %how many superpixel do we have?%
   SPNUM = size (unique (segments), 1);
   %SPNUM=max(segments(:));

   %changing color space for feature vector%
   imHSV = rgb2hsv (imDouble);

   %create feature vector with [averageR averageG averageB averageH averageS averageV]%
   FEATURE = zeros (SPNUM, 6);

   for i=0:SPNUM-1
       [K1,K2] = find (segments == i);
       sz=length(K1);

        intRGB= imDouble([K1,K2,ones(sz,1)]);
        intHSV=(imHSV([K1,K2,ones(sz,1)]));

       FEATURE(i+1,:) = [ sum( intRGB(:,1))/sz sum(intRGB(:,2))/sz sum(intRGB(:,3))/sz sum(intHSV(:,1))/sz sum(intHSV(:,2))/sz sum(intHSV(:,3))/sz];
   end

   clusNum=SPNUM/2;

   RESULT = kmeans (FEATURE, ceil( clusNum));
   newIMAGE = zeros(IH, IW, 3);
   newSegs=zeros(IH,IW);
   colorMultiplier = 1/(clusNum+5);

   for i=1:clusNum
       K = find (RESULT == i);
       valid_segs=zeros(IH,IW);
       for j = 1: size (K,1)


           valid_segs=valid_segs+(segments== K(j));



       end

       newIMAGE (valid_segs~=0) = colorMultiplier * i;
       newSegs(valid_segs~=0)=i;
   end

   imshow (newIMAGE)

   end
   ```